# How to retrieve all keys along with their column names and table name of particular schema in postgresql 9.5?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How to retrieve primary key,foreign key and unique keys along with their respective column names of a particular schema in the the format  described below in postgresql 9.5? I am beginner please help...

```
Table_name|Primary_key_name|pk_column_name|foreign_key_name|fk_colum_name|unique_key_name|uk_column_name
```

Comment: There can be more than one unique or foreign key, and a constraint is not necessarily defined with a single column. You'll get most of this information from the [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) views, particularly `tables`, `table_constraints` and `constraint_column_usage`.

Comment: Yes but i would like to display all the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see basic table details

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'yourTableName';
```

To list out all FORIEN KEY,PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE KEY constraints

```
SELECT tc.constraint_name,
tc.constraint_type,
tc.table_name,
kcu.column_name,
tc.is_deferrable,
tc.initially_deferred,
rc.match_option AS match_type,

rc.update_rule AS on_update,
rc.delete_rule AS on_delete,
ccu.table_name AS references_table,
ccu.column_name AS references_field
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc

LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
ON tc.constraint_catalog = kcu.constraint_catalog
AND tc.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
AND tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name

LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
ON tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog
AND tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema
AND tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name

LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
ON rc.unique_constraint_catalog = ccu.constraint_catalog
AND rc.unique_constraint_schema = ccu.constraint_schema
AND rc.unique_constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name

WHERE lower(tc.constraint_type) in ('foreign key')
```

Comment: Updated, Please check the new one

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for.